# Phonegap clients using MEAN angularjs Nodejs Stack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, cordova

I am developing Web Application using MEAN(Mongo, Express, Angular, Node) JS stack.

I would like to use PhoneGap to compile my clients for Android/iphone native app. At the same time I want to keep same client-side Views & AngularJS code to remain usable for desktop browsers. I am using bootstrapper for Responsive design and it works fine for me on mobile browsers.

I saw, Phonegap require us to include some of it's own Javascript files, and I will be required to have few more .js files in footer of index.html.

- If I pressume, I should not be using server side .jade engine for index.html file, and all my .html should remain in client side.
- will index.html created for phoneGap will cause problem, if I use it for desktop browser? Should I have different index.html for browser and phoneGap input. Can grunt help me in customizing index.html files.

**What are the other things which I should take care of for my needs?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice for you is to separate the projects, Phonegap or Cordova Apps doesn't have a running server, they serve the html files through the `file://` protocol.

> If I pressume, I should not be using server side .jade engine for
>   index.html file, and all my .html should remain in client side.

You presumed correctly, no .jade templates should be used, your views should be plain html files or, if you want, load them as scripts so you don't have to load them on page request increasing app performance.

> will index.html created for phoneGap will cause problem, if I use it
>   for desktop browser? Should I have different index.html for browser
>   and phoneGap input. Can grunt help me in customizing index.html files.

Yes it will, if you try to use an index,html from phonegap on a desktop browser you will get a lot of javascript alerts. Since phonegap.js is expecting to get some events that are fired by cordova when running on the device. And this gets worse if you have Cordova plugins.